# Why does my deployed solution not include plugin and workflow steps?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm attempting to migrate customizations to our new production organization from our dev organization.

I'm using solutions to move the metadata changes but for some reason it doesn't include the steps for the loaded assemblies (plugins and workflows).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add the plugins *and* the steps to the solution?

Comment: I added everything under "Assemblies" where can I explicitly include steps into the solution?

Comment: When you export the solution there are a series of checkboxes you can select or unselect on about the 2nd step I think. Are you definitely checking the appropriate ones? From memory for plugins I think you need the one labelled 'SDK Messaging Steps' - perhaps others can confirm.

Comment: Ahhhh, no i don't check any of them since nothing was intuitive. Like "general" or "customizations" I'll give that a shot now

Comment: +1 for you glosrob. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you have forgotten to add the message processing steps to your solution.

[image]

1. Add your Assemblies at "Plug-in Assemblies"
2. Add steps from the available Assemblies at "Sdk Message Processing Steps" -> "Add Existing" and select the steps from the list.

Comment: I've been using 2011 since the beta and not seen that! Does that work as a replacement to the plugin reg tool?

Comment: @glosrob for the deployment it replaces the plugin registration tool. Not for development. You have to use the tool for the initial registration, configuration and definition of images.

Comment: I'm with you - thanks for heads up. I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @Ckeller You don't have to use the plugin registration tool. If you checkout the developer toolkit thats been included in some of the latest SDK's it provides a way to deploy from within Visual studio, Web Resources, Plugins, Workflows, the lot. Made my life alot easier as a developer!

Comment: @Chris sure that is another option. However I don't like the developer toolkit and the concept which is used for plugin development. But that's only my feeling.

Comment: @Chris I tried using that and get an exception trying to open the project properties designer, also have you had any issues getting anything deployed other than web resources? I can deploy html files but not js or other files for some reason.

Comment: @JonC I have to admit, I've had some issues with it. I can't right click properties either as i get an exception but it's not stopped me using the extension. In short, if you create a plugin or workflow project, you need to add a deployment project. This has to have in it's references the out put from the other projects. It also needs a CRMRegister XML file which defines the plugin steps to register on. Your best bet to see this is from CRM Explorer, right click an entity to create a plugin then see what it generates.

Comment: @Chris Cool. Thanks for the info, +1 for you!